# Map method not displaying updated data coming from useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I'm working on a phonebook app. I'm taking user input from a form and then adding it to my state and then applying the map method on that state to get the user details.
Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const phoneBook = [];

const App = () => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(phoneBook);
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
  const [number, setNumber] = useState("");

  const handleDelete = (name) => {
    let newPhoneBook = contacts.filter((contact) => contact.name !== name);
    setContacts(newPhoneBook);
  };

  const handleAddContact = (userName, number) => {
    let obj = { name: userName, number: number };
    console.log("obj:", obj);
    phoneBook.push(obj);

    console.log("contacts:", contacts);
    console.log("phoneBook:", phoneBook);
  };

  return (
    <div id="main">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-4"></div>

          <div className="col-md-4">
            <div className="App">
              <h2 className="header">PhoneBook App</h2>
              <span
                style={{
                  cursor: "pointer",
                  color: "blue",
                  textDecoration: "underline",
                }}
                onClick={() => setShowForm(!showForm)}
              >
                {showForm ? "Hide Contact Form" : "Create New Contact"}
              </span>

              {showForm && (
                <div className="container">
                  <form className="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeHolder="Name"
                        value={userName}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          e.target.value;
                          setUserName(e.target.value);
                          console.log("userName:", userName);
                          console.log("e.target.value:", e.target.value);
                        }}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeHolder="Number"
                        value={number}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          e.target.value;
                          setNumber(e.target.value);
                          console.log("number:", number);
                          console.log("e.target.value:", e.target.value);
                        }}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="btn btn-primary icon-holder"
                      onClick={() => {
                        handleAddContact(userName, number);
                      }}
                    >
                      Add
                    </button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              )}
              <p>
                There are {contacts.length} contacts saved in this book yet.
              </p>
              {contacts.map((contact, index) => (
                <div key={index} className="contacts">
                  <div class="contact-details">
                    <h5>{contact.name}</h5>
                    <p>{contact.number}</p>
                  </div>
                  <button
                    class="icon-holder"
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleDelete(contact.name);
                    }}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                  <hr />
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The issue I'm facing is that the **contacts** are showing updated value in the console but not showing in the browser through map method.
I have a clue that there is an issue of useState, like how it affects the rendering. One thing I've noted that if I made any change to my code, then the map method shows the saved users at that time.

Here is the codesandbox example for better demonstration: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/todos-app-listed-schkqm?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A8%2C48

Answer (score 2):

You are mutating the state when adding a contact:
Mutating the `phoneBook` array alters the `contacts` state, but doesn't set it, which means that React is not aware of the change and doesn't re-render the new values.

Ditch the `phoneBook` array, and set the `contacts` state directly. Create a new array using the [previous value](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) of contacts using spread plus the new contact.

```
const handleAddContact = (userName, number) => {
  const contact = { name: userName, number: number };

  // create a new contacts array that is combined from the previous values + the new contact
  setContacts(prev => [...prev, contact]);
};
```

I would also use the updater function in `handleDelete`:

```
const handleDelete = (name) => {
  setContacts(prev => prev.filter((contact) => contact.name !== name));
};
```